# Magento 2 - Add subcategories images in Top Navigation Menu

Tags: magento2, php, module, magento2.2, navigation

I want to add subcategories images in Top Navigation Menu, I found this [module](https://catgento.com/2017/03/20/magento-2-display-category-image-in-navigation-menu/) but display only parents categories, I need to be on subcategories.

I want to be like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using these codes to display subcategory image in top navigation menu:

```
$categoryObj = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
$categoryObj->getName() -- This display category Name
$categoryObj->getImageUrl() -- This display category Image
```

Comment: where I need to add this code?